# Serial number auto generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, rowcount

Facing issue in auto generation of serial number.

How can i use `row_number()` in proper manner or is there any alternative to achieve the expected results?

**Note:** I want to write query without using `CASE`.

```
SELECT 
 row_number() over (order by COALESCE(legs.sta, legs.eta) ASC) sno,
 legs.Flight_ID flightId,
 legs.flight,
 legs.flightDate           
FROM Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs LEG
ORDER BY COALESCE(legs.sta, legs.eta) ASC
```

**Current Results:**

```
+------+--------+-------------------------+
| sno  | flight |       flightDate        |
+------+--------+-------------------------+
|    1 | 3K0722 | 2019-01-08 17:10:00.000 |
|    2 | 3K0722 | 2019-01-08 20:20:00.000 |
|    3 | 3K0723 | 2019-01-09 17:10:00.000 |
|    4 | 3K0724 | 2019-01-10 20:20:00.000 |
+------+--------+-------------------------+
```

**Expected Results:**

```
+------+--------+-------------------------+
| sno  | flight |       flightDate        |
+------+--------+-------------------------+
|    1 | 3K0722 | 2019-01-08 17:10:00.000 |
|      |        | 2019-01-08 20:20:00.000 |
|    2 | 3K0723 | 2019-01-09 17:10:00.000 |
|    3 | 3K0724 | 2019-01-10 20:20:00.000 |
+------+--------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: what do you mean is every other next day id is +1 ?

Comment: Looks more like you want `DENSE_RANK` not `ROW_NUMBER`, however, why does the second row have no values for `s.no`,`flt_id` and `flight`? I'm guessing it's a presentation thing, but if that's the case, you should be handling that in your presentation layer, not the data engine.

Comment: Why `Coalesce` ? Why not eg `cast(FlightDate as date)` ? Your expected results are ordered and ranked by the date part of FlightDate

Comment: @Larnu Because of Same flight.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes. it can be done.

Comment: Then I stand by my statement @SantoshJadi ; do that in your presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function in a subquery, then use `DENSE_RANK` window function to create `no` column with `CASE WHEN` expression get `rn = 1` row.

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN DENSE_RANK() over(order by flight) END) no,
       (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN flt_id END) flt_id,
       (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN flight END) flight,
       flightDate
FROM 
(
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY flt_id,flight ORDER BY flightDate) rn
    FROM Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs 
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=066538d17eed1dde917afdd50a5ea48d)

Comment: Expecting the result without using `CASE`

Comment: @SantoshJadi Is there any reason you want to get result without  using `CASE`

Answer (score 2):

You need other `row_number()` :

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY flt_id, flight) AS Sr,
       (CASE WHEN Seq = 1 
             THEN flightId
        END) AS Flight_ID,
       (CASE WHEN Seq = 1 
             THEN flight
        END) AS flight, flightDate
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Flight_ID, flight ORDER BY flightDate) AS Seq,
             legs.Flight_ID flightId, legs.flight, legs.flightDate
      FROM Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs LEG
     ) l;
```

Comment: Expecting the result without using `CASE`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DENSE_RANK` instead of  `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT 
 DENSE_RANK() over (order by COALESCE(legs.sta, legs.eta, legs.ata) ASC) as "s.no",
 legs.Flight_ID flightId
 ,legs.flight
 ,legs.flightDate
FROM Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs LEG
ORDER BY COALESCE(legs.sta, legs.eta, legs.ata) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to following solution, to empty repeating data I required to use CASE expression

Within CTE expression I used Row_Number and Dense_Rank functions in combination with [Partition By clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-row_number-over-partition-by-order-by.aspx)

```
;with cte as (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by flight, flightDate) as num,
        DENSE_RANK() over (order by flight) as [no],
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by flight order by flightDate) as rn,
        flight,
        flightDate
    from Flt_OperativeFlight_Legs legs
)
select
    case when rn > 1 then null else [no] end as [no],
    case when rn > 1 then null else flight end as flight,
    flightDate
from cte
order by num
```

Output is as follows

[image]

Comment: Expecting the result without using `CASE`.

Comment: Yes, I read it. But could not understand the reason behind. To convert repeating values a CASE statement is required. Otherwise NULLs or empty string values will not be seen